# How to erase all elements of STL deque one by one?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

I am facing a weird issue related to erasing elements in a STL list while iterating it. I am aware of the fact that erasing an element invalidates the iterator. So, either

`"testQueue.erase(it++);"` OR `"it = testQueue.erase(it);"`

should be used.

In order to simplify my problem, I tried to remove all elements while iterating a list. However, when using the former mechanism I am getting Segfault.

For your reference below is the complete code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string d1 = "d1";
    std::string d2 = "d2";
    std::string d3 = "d3";

    std::deque<std::string> testQueue;
    testQueue.push_back(d1);
    testQueue.push_back(d2);
    testQueue.push_back(d3);

    std::deque<std::string>::iterator it = testQueue.begin();
    for(; it!=testQueue.end(); ++it){
        std::cout << (*it) << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "========" << std::endl;

    it = testQueue.begin();
    while(it!=testQueue.end()){
        testQueue.erase(it++); // This causes Segfault
        //it = testQueue.erase(it); // This one works just fine.
    }
    std::cout << "========" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "========" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "========" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "========" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "========" << std::endl;

    it = testQueue.begin();
    for(; it!=testQueue.end(); ++it){
        std::cout << (*it) << std::endl;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

I am clueless on why the post-increment approach is not working. Please note that the end goal is not to use this approach for erasing all elements. However, I want to understand what is the difference in the two approaches that I have mentioned.

Comment: Did you read the documentation of erase?

Comment: I don't think you are allowed to modify the number of elements in a collection while iterating over it.

Comment: @leemes Yes, I did. Sorry, if I am missing something very obvious. But could you please point out exactly what I have missed.

Comment: @Patashu erase returns the next valid iterator and using the return of erase works just fine.

Comment: Yes, but using the old iterator doesn't. See my answer, I explained it there.

Comment: Note: while the question title and text mentions "list", the container in the problem is a `std::deque<>`.  The two containers have different guarantees about iterator invalidation so it's important to be clear about which type of container/iterator is involved in the `erase()` operation. The postincrement method would work fine for a `std::list<>` container, but doesn't for a `std::deque<>` for the reason given in [Drew Dormann's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16094780/12711). Please update the question to be consistent in the terms used.

Comment: @MichaelBurr I assumed that the STL list post increment trick will work with STL deque. Purely, a mistake on my part.

Comment: I understand that, and this is a legitimate question. However, I think using the term "list" in the question is misleading and confusing, so it should be changed to wither "dequeue" or "container".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The iterator invalidation rules are different for different containers.

For `std::deque::erase`:

> **all** iterators and references are invalidated, unless the erased members are at an end (front or back) of the deque (in which case only iterators and references to the erased members are invalidated) [23.2.1.3/4]

You are getting a segfault from `testQueue.erase(it++)` because the iterator produced by `it++` has *also* been invalidated.

Comment: Thanks, So, now I think that even though the ` it = testQueue.erase(it);` is working, it is non-standard?

Comment: It doesn't "re-use" an old iterator. So it's totally fine. What "invalidate" corresponds to is when you have old iterators in your code, i.e. when for example just call `erase(it)`, it stays the same and is thus invalidated. But as soon as you assign it to something new (and valid), you're safe again.

Comment: @aakash That is both standard and correct.  `deque::erase` returns a valid iterator.

Comment: Ok! let me put it other way round. The post-increment trick that works with a STL list won't work with STL deque because even though it kept the previous iterator, the previous iterator also is no more valid.

Comment: Yes.  Because it's a `std::deque`.

Answer (score 1):

Because the iterator (and all references for that matter) becomes invalid [after erasing](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque/erase) an element from a `std::deque`. You should use:

```
while(it!=testQueue.end()){
    it = testQueue.erase(it);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[`std::deque::erase`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque/erase) erases the element the iterator points at and returns an iterator pointing to the element after the erased one. It also invalidates the given iterator, so you have to just assign it "to continue".

That's why this works:

```
while(it!=testQueue.end()){
    it = testQueue.erase(it);
}
```

But if you post-increment the iterator and pass it to erase, the element gets erased and *afterwards* the (old) iterator is copied and incremented. Since the old iterator became invalid, the incremented one is so, too.

To clear the whole deque (which you seem to want to do), there is also [`clear()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque/clear)

Comment: @As I mentioned, I wanted to understand the problem (that I was creating myself) when using post-increment operator trick.

Comment: Which is what I explained in the second last paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're always just erasing the first element, why not make life a whole lot simpler:

```
while (!your_list.empty())
    your_list.erase(your_list.begin());
```

Comment: Well, then I don't understand why you don't simply suggest `clear()` ;) But I thought the question asks more about what's wrong with `erase(it++)`.

Comment: @leemes: He seems to want to use a loop for some reason.

Comment: You mean with other stuff? Fair point, but we can only guess about that. In this case, your solution is also worth looking at. +1

Comment: @leemes Actually, I had to delete some elements based on condition and I was getting weird behavior from the iterators. The test program was to post here a simplified version.

Comment: @aakash: `std::remove_if`.

Answer (score 0):

`testQueue.erase(it++);`

this is equal to this

`testQueue.erase(it);`

`it++;`

but "it" points to nothing because it is deleted and cannot be increased.